# Vincular 3 modelos en Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy desarrollando un sistema que entre otras funciones, mostrará las calificaciones de una escuela, por lo que debo manejar niveles, cursos, asignaturas, evaluaciones y notas. Ahora el tema es el siguiente;

No se como puedo relacionar los modelos de Alumnos, Evaluaciones y Notas, es decir, algo como esto en lenguaje natural:

"Cada alumno tiene evaluaciones, y cada una de ellas tiene una nota"

He intentado con relaciones Many to Many pero finalmente las no logro llegar a lo que busco.

La relación que estoy utilizando ahora es esta:

```
class Alumnos extends Model
{
public function evaluaciones(){
    return 
     $this>belongsToMany('App\Evaluaciones','alumnos_evaluaciones')-
     >withPivot('nota')->orderBy('evaluaciones_id','asc');
}

}
```

Si se les ocurre alguna alternativa, o alguien ya ha desarrollado esto antes, se los agradecería!

Comment: Usualmente dejaba la relación con Evaluaciones hasta el belongsToMany y en la entidad Evaluacion hacia un belongsTo con Nota.

Comment: alumno->HasMany->evaluacion y evaluacion->HasOne->nota, a su vez definir la inversa de esas relaciones evaluacion->belongsTo->alumno y nota->belongsTo->evaluacion